# Assert status via jsonpath

Tags: jsonpath, site24x7

I would like to add a monitor to detect unhealthy service and sending alert in that case. 
I've expose a simple REST API - `/healthy` which returns a JSON 
e.g. `{"healthy": true}`.

Then I've added a `REST API Monitor` to my site24x7 account, set the content checks response format to JSON and now I should provide a JSONPath to be asserted.

In a JSONPath online tester when I use `$.healthy` I get `[true]`.
But I guess I should try to assert that return value.

Using following expressions didn't worked

```
$.(@healthy=='true')
$.[?(@.healthy=='true')]
$[?(@.healthy=='true')]
$?(.healthy=='true')
$.healthy=='[true]'
$.healthy==[true]
$.healthy==['true']
```

Thought I should evaluate the assertion expression using `()` or filtering.

How I can assert the return healthy status?

In site24x7 example I see an example for JSONPath expression

`$..[?(@.overallStatus=='true')]`

which i couldn't make it work in my case

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's extraordinarily poorly documented but I looked at the examples for [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) and eventually found this worked:

```
$.[?(@.healthy == true)]
```

Since your struct is so basic I think this might work as well:

```
[?(@.healthy == true)]
```

You can try it out on https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/